# call_count mocked class method call returns 0 instead of expected 1?

Tags: python

I need to test the following decorator:

**deco_a.py**:

```
from ModuleA import ClassA
x = ClassA()

def deco_a(p1, p2):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print('...') # this line prints, so x.func_1 ran
            x.func_1(...)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

The code runs without any error. I tried to create the following test case to check if `x.func1()` is called once,

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('....ClassA')
    def test_called_once(self, mocked):
        
        @deco_a(p1=1, p2=2):
        def test():
            return 42

        test()

        assert mocked.return_value.func_1.call_count == 1 # actual call_count == 0
```

However, the test failed because the actual `call_count` is equal to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking the wrong destination.

When you instance `x = ClassA()`, that variable is stored in memory for the session (even before your test starts). Then you create a mock to the class, which is no longer called.

You should either mock directly the method `ClassA.func_1` or the global variable `your_module.x`, then you will get the right call_count.

Comment: How to mock directly the mothod `ClassA.func_1`? Or the global variable `deco_a.x`?

Comment: Change `@mock.patch('....ClassA')` to `@mock.patch('....ClassA.func_1')`, then your assertion will be `assert mocked.call_count == 1`.